# Авторизация пользователя в приложении Java

Tags: авторизация, java

Доброго времени суток! Простите заранее за вопрос. Я новичок, далеко не всё знаю.

Проблема заключается в следующем. Есть некоторое десктопное приложение, в котором для доступа к окну с настройками нужно вводить пароль (без логина, просто пароль для возможности изменения настроек). Каким образом можно это организовать? И как хранить пароль в программе?

Comment: Вопрос в одном - как задается пароль?

Comment: @smackmychi, в принципе, да. Как организовать его хранение внутри приложения? Как зашифровать? Где про это можно прочесть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я тоже далеко не всё знаю, но мне кажется, что тут есть 2 варианта: хранить пароль в файле или хранить пароль в коде программы. В коде не советую, потому что тогда для изменения пароля придётся перекомпилировать класс. Остаётся вариант с файлом. Можете хранить в открытом виде, но лучше естественно зашифровать и спрятать от глаз пользователя куда-нибудь подальше.

Comment: @Dazar, спасибо за ответ! Не подскажите, где можно почитать про шифрование пароля?

Comment: @harooln, как сказал @smackmychi, "Дак, где угодно".  
Зависит всё от того, от кого вы ходите защитить данные - от обычного юзера или от продвинутого.
От обычного спасёт любое кодирование, хоть md5 делайте. Но от продвинутого это не спасёт, гуглите про проблемы и "декодирование" md5. И вообще, любая статья на тему "шифрирование паролей" вам поможет

Comment: @Dazar, огромное спасибо!

Comment: @harooln, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Дак, где угодно. Ищите описания криптографических алгоритмов, хватит даже википедии, чтобы иметь общее представление о том, какую устойчивость каждый алгоритм имеет и с какими данными работает...
Если пароль задается вами, а не пользователем, то можно хранить в любом удобном классе. Хоть и в классе главного окна (шифровать не требуется). Если же пользователь вводит его при первом запуске или регистрации нового пользователя приложения, то хранить опять же в любом доступном программе месте, тогда придется шифровать.

Придумать можно много чего. Вплоть до того, чтобы запрашивать у пользователя ввод пароля в числовом виде, преобразуете данное число в дату, сохраняете в нужном месте. В итоге имеете какую-то дату, к которой не придраться. Тут все на ваш вкус и цвет.